# Where did they get the router context

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On the example folder of `react-router` where did they get the **router** context on `Login.js`. I'm very confused on this on. For reference, here's the [link for the Login.js file](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-with-shared-root/components/Login.js).

I didn't see any variable declartion on **router**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`RouterContext`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/RouterContext.js) has `childContextType` **`router`**

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/RouterContext.js#L36

```
childContextTypes: {
    history: object,
    location: object.isRequired,
    router: object.isRequired
},
```

And `login.js` has this.

```
contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
},
```

This is based on [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)

Comment: So if add `contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
},` on any of my components this context will be available?

Comment: @mateeyow I believe so, haven't really used `context` yet.

Comment: This is very confusing because on RouteContext they defined the context as **route** but as you stated when they required the context on contextTypes it became **router**

Comment: @mateeyow oops, changed it from `router` to `route`. Just answered this based on my understanding of `childContext`. Searching for the `router` in my `react-router` modules. It's still basically the same idea though. Somewhere in `react-router` they're adding the `router` context that's why they can use it in child components.

Comment: @mateeyow Found the source code! edited the answer to reflect it.